# Why do my Perl bigints have a decimal place?

Tags: perl, string, bigint

If I do use a big integer in substr:

```
use BigInt;
$acct_hash = substr(('99999999999912345' + $data[1]),0,15);
```

why is the result still `9.9999999999912`?

I was expecting `999999999999912`. Is there something like:

```
$data[1] = substr(to_char('999999999999991234'),0,15);
```

in Perl?

Comment: I have change it to bigint; and is the same result

how can i mult. this by 1000000000000000

Answer (score 3):

To get the first 15 digits of the sum of `$a` and `$b`, do this:

```
use bigint;
my $a = "99999999999912345";  # works with or without quotes
my $b = "111";                # works with or without quotes
print substr(0 + $a + $b, 0, 15), "\n";
```

The reason why your code didn't work as expected is that Perl does a floating point addition for `$a + $b` if both `$a` and `$b` are strings, even if `use bigint` is in effect. Example:

```
use bigint;
print     1234567890123456789  +  2 , "\n";  #: 1234567890123456791
print    "1234567890123456789" +  2 , "\n";  #: 1234567890123456791
print     1234567890123456789  + "2", "\n";  #: 1234567890123456791
print    "1234567890123456789" + "2", "\n";  #: 1.23456789012346e+18
print 0 + 1234567890123456789  + "2", "\n";  #: 1234567890123456791
```

This behavior is a quirk in the Perl `bigint` module. You can work it around by prepending a `0 +` (as shown above), thus forcing bigint addition instead of floating point addition. Another workaround can be `Math::BigInt->new($a) + $b` instead of `0 + $a + $b`.

Comment: Relying on Math::BigInt isn't a workaround - seems like the standard thing to do.  Works both by using $a->badd($b) as well as the overridden '+';

Comment: Relying on Math::BigInt is indeed a workaround in my answer. It is a workaround for the quirk that Perl treats `"$a" + "$b"` as a floating point addition in `use bigint` mode.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're running into is a problem with string interpretation.  Try this code:

```
use bigint;
print(99999999999912345 + 99999999999912345, "\n");
```

And compare it to the very similar:

```
use bigint;
print('99999999999912345' + '99999999999912345', "\n");
```

Using single quotes around your numbers is turning them into strings, and seems to get around `bigint`.